# pass a control name as a variable and then hide a control using that variable

Tags: c++-cli

I'm building a function that will receive the name of a (in this case) `FlowLayoutPanel` as variable `showme` and I want to use this variable to set that particular panel visible.

ps I am new to c++ !

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is not working

```
   void JommSwitchPanels(FlowLayoutPanel^ showme)
   {
       
       //stuff here to hide the menu panels
       
        showme.Visable = true;//the error is shown on showme
               
       flowfleet1->Visible = false;            
       flowhr->Visible = false;
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`showme` is a handle to a `FlowLayoutPanel` object.
Dereferencing a [handle to object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) in c++/cli is done using the arrow operator (`->`).
You also have a typo in the property name (`Visable`/`Visible`).

Therefore you need to change:

```
showme.Visable = true;
```

To:

```
//----vv--------------
showme->Visible = true;
```